# Linux set hardware clock in UTC and system time in local time

Tags: linux, opensuse, timezone, clock

Due to some reasons, I have to remotely set hardware clock time in UTC and system time in local time. My OS is OpenSUSE 13.1 and my tool is only the `hwclock` command. What I do so far:

1. Synchronize time use `ntpdate` command-> system time is correctly displayed in local time with time zone Indochina (GMT+7)

```
date
Tue Aug 30 14:00:00 ICT 2016
```

2. Set hardware clock to UTC

```
hwclock --systohc --utc
```

3. Reboot, check BIOS Time. Hardware clock is already in UTC Time, ie 7:00 AM.

4. Log in to machine. System time is incorrect.

```
 date
 Tue Aug 30 07:00:00 ICT 2016
 date -u
 Tue Aug 30 00:00:00 UTC 2016
```

5. Correct time using `hwclock` (Note: `--localtime` instead of `--utc` here doesn't work)

```
hwclock --hctosys --utc
date
Tue Aug 30 14:00:00 ICT 2016
date -u
Tue Aug 30 07:00:00 UTC 2016
```

6. Reboot, system time is incorrect again. Repeat step 5 to correct it.

This is driving me crazy since I don't know what is wrong. Please help, I don't want to correct the system time every time the machine boot!

PS: Content of `/etc/adjtime`

```
0.000000 1472543544 0.000000
1472543544
UTC
```

Comment: What does `/etc/adjtime` contain?

Comment: @StephenKitt I've updated my question with /ect/adjtime content